# How can I resolve 'Make clean' error in Command Prompt

Tags: cmd, makefile, mingw-w64

I created a batch file, for a project I am working on, which works as expected from a command in MINGW64, but not from a command in CMD.

I have the same problem with 'make clean', which, only in CMD prints an error.

```
make[1]: Entering directory 'C:/Users/src/Probs'
rm -rf ./obj ./mod
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, rm -rf ./obj ./mod, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make[1]: *** [makefile:114: clean] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/src/Probs'
make: *** [makefile:56: clean] Error 2
```

Would you please comment on that?

Answer (score 0):

When you run your script in command prompt it doesn't recognize the rm command. It doesn't exist on command prompt.
You can change it to use rd instead:

```
rd /s /q "path"
```

Or you can install cygwin, which has rm as well as ls etc...
And add "Cygwin\bin" to your Environment Path variable